# Spring Boot Testing: Cannot Autowire springSecurityFilterChain on Test Class

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I am still wresting with various annotations in setting up a test context under spring boot.

I have been referring to [this article](http://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles/), which is refreshingly clear on how to deal with various contexts under **Spring Boot**. The problem remaining is that I cannot seem to find an annotation combination that will make the `springSecurityFilterChain` visible in both the **main application context** (driven from here):

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

and from the test application context begun here:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestPersistenceConfig.class,MvcConfig.class,SecurityConfig.class},loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
//@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {TestPersistenceConfig.class,MvcConfig.class,SecurityConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ApplicationIntegrationTest {

    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    //@Resource(name="springSecurityFilterChain")
    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    private ClientDao clientDao;

    @Autowired
    private RoleDao roleDao;


    UUID key = UUID.fromString("f3512d26-72f6-4290-9265-63ad69eccc13");


    @Before
    public void setup() {

        // using the web application to initate the mock
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain).build();

        // our other choice is using another controller config
        //mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.annotationConfigSetup(ExampleApplicationContext.class).build();

        // here we should build up the data structure using hibernate
        List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();

        Client clientEN = new Client();
        clientEN.setDeviceId("444444444");
        clientEN.setLanguage("en-EN");
        clientEN.setAgentId("444444444|68:5b:35:8a:7c:d0");
        Client clientENDomain = clientDao.save(clientEN);
        clients.add(clientENDomain);

        List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        Role roleUser = new Role();
        roleUser.setRole("user");
        Role roleUserDomain = roleDao.save(roleUser);
        roles.add(roleUserDomain);

        Role roleAdmin = new Role();
        roleAdmin.setRole("admin");
        Role roleAdminDomain = roleDao.save(roleAdmin);
        roles.add(roleAdminDomain);

        User user = new User();
        user.setLogin("user");
        user.setPassword("password");
        user.setClients(clients);
        user.setRoles(roles);

        userDao.save(user);

    }

    @Test
    public void thatViewBootstrapUsesHttpNotFound() throws Exception {

        // testing that a correct login into the form will result in a cookie being set
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/login")
                .param("username", "user").param("password", "password")).andReturn();
        Cookie c = result.getResponse().getCookie("my-cookie");

        Cookie[] cookies = result.getResponse().getCookies();
        for (int i = 0; i <= cookies.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("cookie " + i + " name: " + cookies[i].getName());
            System.out.println("cookie " + i + " value: " + cookies[i].getValue());
        }
        //assertThat(c.getValue().length(), greaterThan(10));

        // No cookie; 401 Unauthorized
        mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());

        // With cookie; 200 OK
        mockMvc.perform(get("/").cookie(c)).andExpect(status().isOk());

        // Logout, and ensure we're told to wipe the cookie
        result = mockMvc.perform(delete("/session")).andReturn();
        c = result.getResponse().getCookie("my-cookie");
        assertThat(c.getValue().length(), is(0));
    }

}
```

By the way `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` doesn't seem to work in any circumstance, contrary to the doco. The security config is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@ComponentScan({
        "com.touchcorp.touchpoint.security",
        "com.touchcorp.touchpoint.service",
        "com.touchcorp.touchpoint.model.dao"})
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    DeviceUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {


        auth
                .authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }
    }

    @Order(2)
    @Configuration
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error=1")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        }
    }

    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/")
                .setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

}
```

Can anyone see why the `springSecurityFilterChain` is invisible ("No beans of `FileterChainProxy` type found"). Thanks, I'm pulling my hair out here.

I think I am just a bit unclear as to the purpose of all the annotations. The Spring Boot reference is good, but it doesn't really extend beyond an established baseline. It seems that as soon as you have to combine spring security, hibernate and mvc together, it starts to get complicated and its not clear as to what one is to do.

Comment: It looks like context parent-child problem. You cannot autowire beans created at child context on parent context, but the reverse will work

Comment: Thanks gerrytan, but I'm not sure what you are saying

Comment: It's not a parent context problem because there is only one context.

Answer (score 0):

I would be worried about why `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` is not working because it is in extensive use elsewhere (e.g. in Spring Boot samples) and it works fine there. Maybe a classpath issue? How about linking to a complete project that others can try to reproduce your problem?

You have 2 different application contexts (one for the test and one in your `Application`) so it wouldn't be surprising if they behaved differently. In particular the `Application` has `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and you test (as far as we can see) does not, so there's one difference that's worth looking into. But nothing is obviously wrong with the test.

Here's an example of a test that autowires the Security filter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/samples/oauth2/sparklr/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/samples/config/ApplicationConfigurationTests.java. It works. Here's another: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/uaa/src/test/java/org/cloudfoundry/identity/uaa/mock/audit/AuditCheckMvcMockTests.java.

Comment: I spoke too soon. It seems that the springSecurityFilterChain is not escaping the config after all. What seems to be happening instead is that a new, vanilla springSecurityFilterChain is autowired in the tests and not the one that was setup under TestPersistenceConfig. As a result the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter fires rather than my DeviceUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you Dave Syer,

I have made a couple of changes that seem to resolve the various missing pieces:

a test class that begins with:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestApplicationConfig.class,TestPersistenceConfig.class,MvcConfig.class,SecurityConfig.class},loader=AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ApplicationIntegrationTest {
```

and a "marker" Config class, which acts as a component scanner:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.touchcorp.touchpoint"})
public class TestApplicationConfig {
}
```

All pars seem to work aside from the data layer, which cannot find any of my domain objects, but this appears to be restricted to the JPA/Hibernate config, not so much an application problem.

Thanks again.